# What is the difference between multipart/form-data and application-x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: java, android, http, multipartform-data

I have a very basic question:

What is the difference between `multipart/form-data` and `application-x-www-form-urlencoded`?

How does data transfer take place in both of these?

And also, can we use both in same request.

Comment: Related post -[application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4007969/465053)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Checkout this answer for your basic question about difference**

[application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

**Can we use both for the same request:**

Answer is : NO

**Moral:** Byte heavy transmission should use Multipart-Form-Data, for everything else there's application-x-www-form-urlencoded.